# Compile-time generation of array using an interleaved formatter

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, variadic

I am trying to build a compile-time generated array of a certain type, based on a template parameter pack of some types. The array generation works just fine if the types are used directly. However, I'd like to apply a tag on each each and have them be interleaved in the generated array.

So, this is where I am at:

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
static constexpr attributes_t make_attrs = {...};
```

and instantiated by (size is calculated elsewhere)

```
attributes_t attributes[sizeof...(Ts)] = {make_attrs<Ts>...};
```

What I would really like is to be able to make the latter tag each type in `Ts`, say with `First` and `Second` tags, such that I can produce a type-list like this

```
NewTs = First<Ts[0]>, Second<Ts[0]>, First<Ts[1]>, Second<Ts[1]>, First<Ts[2]>, Second<Ts[2]>, ...
```

It's important that the `First` and `Second` taggers are interleaved like that. The intent is to be able to control the instantiation of each one by its tagged version.

In my naivity I tried something like this

```
attributes_t attributes[2 * sizeof...(Ts)] = {make_attrs<First<Ts>, Second<Ts>>...};
```

in the hopes that it would expand the pack in the interleaved pattern. Unfortunately that didn't work - I am hoping that there exists a similarly simple and concise solution :)

There must be a way to do this, I'm sure. I have looked through various posts here and there and cannot find a solution that has worked yet, or perhaps I just didn't quite understand it.

I hope you have a great solution :)

Answer (score 3):

As usual [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) might help:

```
template <typename T> struct First{};
template <typename T> struct Second{};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Types
{
};

template <typename Seq, typename Tuple>
struct Impl;

template <std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
struct Impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple>
{
    using type =
        Types<std::conditional_t<Is % 2 == 0,
                                 First<std::tuple_element_t<Is / 2, Tuple>>,
                                 Second<std::tuple_element_t<Is / 2, Tuple>>>...>;
};


template <typename... Ts>
using makeRes = typename Impl<std::make_index_sequence<2 * sizeof...(Ts)>,
                              std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Types<First<int>, Second<int>,
                                   First<char>, Second<char>>,
                             makeRes<int, char>>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKn9s84s6)

if `attributes_t` is default constructible, assigning might be shorter:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr std::array<attributes_t, 2 * sizeof...(Ts)> make_attributes()
{
    std::array<attributes_t, 2 * sizeof...(Ts)> res{};
    std::size_t index = 0;
    ((attributes[index++] = make_attrs<First<Ts>>,
      attributes[index++] = make_attrs<Second<Ts>>),
     ...);
    return res;
}
```

Folding expression is C++17, you can workaround that in C++11/C++14 with initializer_list trick:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr std::array<attributes_t, 2 * sizeof...(Ts)> make_attributes()
{
    std::array<attributes_t, 2 * sizeof...(Ts)> res{};
    std::size_t index = 0;
    const int dummy[] = {0, (
        attributes[index++] = make_attrs<First<Ts>>,
        attributes[index++] = make_attrs<Second<Ts>>,
        0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // silent warning for unused variable
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I am hoping for a more concise solution, which doesn't involve the std::index_sequence. Something like

`attributes_t attributes[2 * sizeof...(Ts)] = {make_attrs<First<Ts>, Second<Ts>>...};`

Unfortunately this didn't work as I expected :(

Comment: @CasperB.Hansen: added shorter version if `attributes_t` is default constructible.

Comment: Closer - much closer! Only two things to note about it, the fold expression is a C++17 feature, and the array is a standard C-array in my case. But I guess the array part would be relatively easy to change.

Comment: There are similar construct to mimic fold expression in C++11/C++14 (with `initializer_list`). It is more verbose and tricky and less clear.

Comment: I did look into std::initializer_list for a possible solution, but didn't succeed.

Would you mind providing an example? Just for curiousity :)

Comment: @CasperB.Hansen: added C++14 version (you have to drop the `constexpr` for C++11).